# get visitors country on IP based using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend, currency

I want to get the visitors country based on their IP using javascript. I have made some changes in my html code. I found some piece of code here on stackoverflow which works good, but I don't know how to extract the country from the array.

**Code**

```
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="response"></pre>
```

**What I want:**

I have a pricing table on my html page, now I want to change the price symbole only according to the country of the visitors.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the code you've provided do? What do you want it to do and how did you try to achieve it?

Comment: `response` is not an array but an object and that object has two country related properties `country_name` and `country_code`. So what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: in your get request i dont see you sending any IP address to the endpoint to retrieve the country , so we have no idea what your code does

Comment: GalAbra please read the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `fetch` and avoiding jQuery altogether?

```
fetch('https://api.ipdata.co')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.country_code));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Edit: Changes the text value of the element with Id `response` to the currency symbol returned.

```
fetch('https://api.ipdata.co')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    document.querySelector('#response').textContent = data.currency.symbol;
});
```

Comment: how to inject it in my html, like how to change the currency symbole using the response i got from the 'fetch('https://api.ipdata.co')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.country_code));'

Answer (score -1):

Check if this works:

```
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
    $("#response").html(response.currency.symbol);
}, "jsonp");
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="response"></pre>
```

Comment: This would append the country currency symbol ($ for eg.) to the ID as HTML. Hope you were looking to achieve this.